# How to check which Emacs I am using?

Tags: emacs

I have two Emacs (Aquamacs and text-based Emacs) on my Mac.

In my `.emacs` file, I can check if I'm using Aquamacs with ...

```
(boundp 'aquamacs-version)
```

How can I check if I'm using text based emacs?

### EDIT

Jürgen Hötzel's answer works, but for text based emacs, using

```
(unless (null window-system) ...)
```

is better as `(window-system)` is not defined.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
M-x emacs-version
```

ad some more characters here......

Sorry, from .emacs, just call

```
(emacs-version)
```

Comment: Or in recent Emacses, just `version`.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was answered a long time ago, but I found another answer by typing `emacs --help`. This gives a list of options in which you can find `emacs --version`.

In my case, `emacs --version` prints: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`.

I have only tested this solution on Linux with my current version of Emacs. I do not know if the same solution applies to Windows, or to older versions of Emacs, but in theory it should.

Comment: It does work on Windows, at least with GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 4):

```
(if (window-system)
    "window-based"
  "text-based")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could use this:

```
(if (or (eq window-system 'ns)
        (eq window-system 'mac))
    (message "hello, world!"))
```

It will only print "hello, world!" when you run a graphical Emacs in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Errr... `(not (boundp 'aquamacs-version))`, perhaps?