# Installing git-auto-commit-mode

Tags: git, emacs

I try to install `git-auto-commit-mode` base on [this](http://projects.ryuslash.org/git-auto-commit-mode/) manual.

- downloaded a package content from https://github.com/ryuslash/git-auto-commit-mode:

[image]

- moved that package to some directory in my computer
- in console in my some repository I put:
  `(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/kuna/Library/git-auto-commit-mode-master")`

But as an output I got:

```
>
>
>
```

I need to install program which help me test auto commits when I change some files, or add new ones, or remove.

What should i do to install this and try how it work? I am very new with doing such things. Need very simple and basic answer. Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the installation modes listed in [`ryuslash/git-auto-commit-mode`](https://github.com/ryuslash/git-auto-commit-mode), you could consider the [Directory Variable one](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables).

> If you put a file with a special name `.dir-locals.el` in a directory, Emacs will read it when it visits any file in that directory or any of its subdirectories, and apply the settings it specifies to the file’s buffer.
>
> Emacs searches for `.dir-locals.el’ starting in the directory of the visited file, and moving up the directory tree.

So add a `.dir-locals.el` file at the root of your git repo, and put in it (if you’re using Emacs 24 or newer)
:

```
((nil . ((eval git-auto-commit-mode 1))))
```

Comment: How to check what Emacs do I use? What is Emacs24?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4630686/6309. For recent enough Emacs, a simple `emacs --version` works. "Emacs 24" means: if you are using Emacs 24 or a more recent version (24.1, 24.2, ...). See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsReleaseDates.

Comment: I added the file `.dir-locals.el` with content `((nil . ((eval git-auto-commit-mode 1))))`, then changed some file, but nothing was committed automatically. Why?

Comment: So far I installed emacs 24, but what about `git-auto-commit-mode` - what should I actually do?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I don't have other information except the one in the answer and http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables